# Javascript won't work with the html

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i'm having a problem here, when i'm using jsbin it all works fine with the javascript, html and the css where they all manage to work together. But since it's better and easier to work in brackets or sublime text 2 i tried to use them. And first i couldn't get the javascript to work together with the html even though i connected them both correctly. I even tried putting all the javascript code inside a script tag in the html as you can see here:

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css1.css">
    </head>

    <body  background="https://guideinparadise.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/down-below2.jpg">
      <h1>Fiskaren</h1>
      <img id="fiskespo" src ="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/03/24/17/07/fishing-rod-295096_960_720.png">
    <p>Sekunder:</p>
      <p id="klocka"></p> 


        <script> 
            document.body.style.cursor = 'none'; // tar bort muspekaren
    (document).mousemove(function (e) { //gör en funktion för musen
       ('#fiskespo').offset({  // tar fram bilden
            left: e.pageX + -190,  //positonerar musen på bilden
            top: e.pageY + -110//positonerar musen på bilden
        });
    });

     var b = 1; 
      for (var i= 0; i<5;i++){ // skapar en loop som skriver ut 5 stycken bilder på fiskar
      fisk(b);
      }
    function getRandomPosition(element) {
        var x = document.body.offsetHeight-element.clientHeight;
        var y = document.body.offsetWidth-element.clientWidth;
        var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random()*x);
        var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random()*y);

        return [randomX,randomY];   
    } 
    function fisk(skala) { 

        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute("style", "position:fixed;");//positionerar dom
        img.setAttribute("src", "http://i.imgur.com/K9egEbW.jpg"); // tar fram bilderna
        document.body.appendChild(img); 
        var xy = getRandomPosition(img); // ger xy random position
        img.style.top = xy[0] + 'px';// gör att de ej kan flyttas från ruta 1
        img.style.left = xy[1] + 'px';
       $(img).click(function(){ $(this).remove();}); //skapar en onclick funktion som gör så att om man klickar på bilden försvinner den

    }
      myTimer = setInterval(myCounter, 1000); //bestämmer hur lång tiden ska vara (1000 = 1 vanlig sekund)
      var seconds = 0; //sekunden den börjar på
      function myCounter() {
        document.getElementById("klocka").innerHTML = ++seconds; //räknar klockan i sekunder
    }   
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And this didn't work either. And i find this really wierd since it works on jsbin but not on a better program. Anybody have a clue on what i might be missing or if there is problems with the programs i'm using. Here is the css code aswell if you want to take a look at it all together.

```
#fiskespo{
  width: 120px;
 z-index: 2;

}

body{
  background-size: 100%;

}

h1{
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: red;
  z-index: 3;

}

p{
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: -260px;
  z-index: 3;

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't work how?  Use browser devtools, open the console, reload your page, check for errors.

Comment: What do you mean by don't work? Be more specific.

Comment: Nothing from the javascript shows up, the css work but when it gets to the javascript nothing show up. In the javascript i have a timer and code that will spawn 5 images but nothing of it pops up when i open the html code in a webbrowser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `jQuery` in your page and also use `$` here:

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e) { ... });
$('#fiskespo').offset({ ... });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j2wnLn7e/1/

Comment: Glad to help!  Would you mind accepting this as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

It probably has something to do with how you are opening the files. It probably can't find your script file and/or css file. Are you using a localhost? The simplest way is to use a python simple http server. You will need python on your computer for this work. Newer macs have it preinstalled. Place all your files in a single folder. Navigate to that folder in the command line. And run the command:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

This will launch a localhost with the files in that location. Use the port it shows after you run the command. In the browser go to (using the port it gives you):

```
localhost:port
```

Also not sure if it was a typo but you don't have a closing script tag.